# Локальные переменные в ассемблерной вставке Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер, masm

Создаю ассемблерную вставку MASM в визуалке, нужно объявить переменную в ассемблерной вставке. Знаю, что лучше объявлять сишную переменную и юзать её потом в коде, но у меня задача заключается именно в объявлении переменной в вставке, как это можно сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int retres;

    __asm{
        var1 db 10 //пример создания переменной, не работает

        mov eax, var1
        mov ebx, 3
        sub edx, edx
        cdq
        imul ebx
        mov ecx, 20
        cmp eax, ecx
        setl eax
        mov retres, eax
    }
     cout << retres;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых должно быть db вместо byte, во-вторых это создаст вам переменную прямо посреди кода, и будет попытка выполнить ее как код. Если вы не будете пытаться ее перезаписать (что вызовет ошибку, т.к. секция кода по умолчанию защищена от записи), то можно сделать jmp через нее.

Comment: Нужна полноценная переменная, с возможностью перезаписи, вроде той, которая в полноценном коде объявляется в сегменте data

Comment: Тогда делайте полноценный ассемблерный модуль.

Comment: А вот нужно именно вставкой вот и ищу решение всё перерыл уже)

Comment: Это учебное задание или вы просто так хотите? Насколько я знаю, то что вы хотите невозможно.

Comment: Учебное задание сам бы я объявил переменные в Си)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в таких случаях принято использовать пространство стека для хранения переменных

```
#define var01 [esp - 4] // определение через дефин для удобства и наглядности
mov var01, 10 // присвоить значение / инициализировать
```

не могу гарантировать что "препод" считает такое "решение" "верным"